# How to Reset a Xamarin forms Navigation stack from a Xamarin droid Assist activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Helo I am working on adding an assist feature to my app that when the user holds down on the home button an android activity opens with cards that the user can click on that then opens the xamarin forms page in question for example when the math card is clicked the MathPage xamarin forms page opens this works but if I have the xamarin forms app running in the background it loads the home screen layout regardless of what button i click. If I close the xamarin forms app from multitasking and hold down on the home button and click on the math card it will open the MathPage.

heres my android Activity code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

namespace Appname.Droid
{
[Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance, Theme = "@style/Theme.Transparent")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionAssist }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault })]    
    public class ToolBelt : Activity
    {


        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ToolBelt);

        }


        //Code That Opens The Math Part!

        [Java.Interop.Export("math")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick4(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {

            var intent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("page", "Math");
            StartActivity(intent);
        }


        //Code That Opens The Science Part!

        [Java.Interop.Export("science")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick9(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {

            var intent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("page", "Science");
            StartActivity(intent);
        }



        //Code That Opens The Handwriting  Part!

        [Java.Interop.Export("english")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick10(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {

            var intent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("page", "Handwriten");
            StartActivity(intent);
        }



        //Code That Opens The Flascards  Part!

        [Java.Interop.Export("flashcard")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick11(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {

            var intent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("page", "Flashcards");
            StartActivity(intent);
        }

        //Code That Opens The Internet  App!

        [Java.Interop.Export("web")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick8(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("http://www.google.com");
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
            StartActivity(intent);
        }



        //Code That Opens The Gmail App!

        [Java.Interop.Export("email")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick3(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {
            var intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.gm");
            StartActivity(intent);
        }



        //Code That Opens The Books App!

        [Java.Interop.Export("books")] // The value found in android:onClick attribute.
        public void btnOneClick5(View v) // Does not need to match value in above attribute.
        {
            var intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.books");
            StartActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

here's the MainActivity droid code:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AppName.Droid;
using AppName.Data;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MainActivity))]
namespace AppName.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "AppName", Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, SchoolTools.PackageInterface
    {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            var page = Intent.GetStringExtra("page");
            LoadApplication(new App(page));


        }

        public IList<Apps> GetInstalledApps()
        {
            IList<Apps> apps = new List<Apps>();
            var pkgInfos = global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.PackageManager.GetInstalledPackages(PackageInfoFlags.Activities);
            foreach(var pi in pkgInfos)
            {
                // skip system packages
                if (pi.ApplicationInfo.DataDir.StartsWith("/data/user/"))
                {
                    Apps app = new Apps(pi.ApplicationInfo.LoadLabel(global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.PackageManager).ToString(), pi.PackageName);
                    if (!apps.Contains(app))
                    {
                        apps.Add(app);
                    }
                }
            }
            return apps;
        }

        public bool Launch(string package)
        {
            var intent = Application.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(package);
            bool retVal = IsIntentAvailable(intent);
            if (retVal)
            {
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        private static bool IsIntentAvailable(Intent intent)
        {
            return intent != null && Application.Context.PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, 0).Count != 0;
        }
    }
}
```

heres my app.cs code:

```
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AppName
{
    public class App : Application
    {

        public App(string pageName = "AppNameHome")
        {
            switch (pageName)
            {
                case "Math":

                    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MathPage());

                    break;


                    case "Science":
                    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Science.ScienceToolsPage());
                    break;

                        case "Handwriten":
                    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Handwriting.HandwritingToolsPage());
                    break;

                            case "Flashcards":
                    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Flashcards.FlashCardHome());
                    break;

                    default:
                    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new AppNameHome());

                    break;


            }



        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem i needed to add SingleInstance to the main activity as well is nohistory = true heres the code needed to fix this issue:

```
[Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance, NoHistory = true,
 Label = "AppName", Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```